# Runnin magento unde the wordpress as a subdirectory over Nginx

Tags: magento, nginx, url-rewriting

I am running magento under the Wordpress(Wordpress on the root and mangento under a subdirectory "/shop"). Previously I was running this under the Apache, So everything was running fine with separate .htaccess under the /shop folder.

As I move the server over NginX, all the internal magento URL showing 404. Please help me to solve this problem. Please suggest me how can I run the Magento under the /shop folder with Wordpress.

Here is my NginX Configuration file:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;

root   /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

error_log           /var/www/logs/error.log;
access_log         /var/www/logs/access.log;

### gZip Setting ###
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
### gZip End ###

location / {
if ($http_host !~ "^www\."){
     rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$http_host/$1 redirect;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location /shop/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}

location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

    expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, Here is my new configuration file:

```
server {
listen   80;

server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;

root   /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

error_log           /var/www/logs/domain-error-ssl.log;
access_log         /var/www/logs/domain-access-ssl.log;

### gZip Setting ###
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
### gZip End ###

location / {
    if ($http_host !~ "^www\."){
  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://www.$http_host/$1 redirect;
}
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

### Configuration for shop ###
location /shop {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires 30d;
    if ($uri ~ "^/index.php/admin.*$"){
            rewrite ^/index.php/admin(.*) /admin$1 redirect;
    }
}

location ~ ^/shop/(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }
location /shop/var/export/ { internal; }
location @handler { rewrite / /shop/index.php; }
### END Configuration for shop ###

location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
    expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
    fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
    #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    #fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
}
```

}

Comment: we use something similar, but now have the problem that /checkout and /customer/account for example returns a 404 ....